# Taking in a list as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, list, parameters

I wrote a function that takes in 3 integers as a parameter, as i am given three pixels, and i need to return the pixel with the smallest distance from the average red, green, and blue values across all pixels.

```
def get_best_pixel(pixel1, pixel2, pixel3):
   
    red_average = (pixel1.red + pixel2.red + pixel3.red) // 3
    green_average = (pixel1.green + pixel2.green + pixel3.green) // 3
    blue_average = (pixel1.blue + pixel2.blue + pixel3.blue) // 3
    pixel1_dist = get_pixel_dist(pixel1, red_average, green_average, blue_average)
    pixel2_dist = get_pixel_dist(pixel2, red_average, green_average, blue_average)
    pixel3_dist = get_pixel_dist(pixel3, red_average, green_average, blue_average)
    if pixel1_dist <= pixel2_dist and pixel1_dist <= pixel3_dist:
        return pixel1
    elif pixel3_dist <= pixel1_dist and pixel3_dist <= pixel2_dist:
        return pixel3
    elif pixel2_dist <= pixel1_dist and pixel2_dist <= pixel3_dist:
        return pixel2
```

but i want to convert the function so it takes in those integers from a list instead:

```
def get_best_pixel(pixel_list):

    pixel_list = []
```

I am using SimpleImage btw.

Comment: What do you mean by "so each pixel in the list can be taken in with 3 RGB values" - each pixel would only ever have a single R, G and B value, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Grismar yeah i meant 3 values, one for red, green, and blue

Comment: Lists work as parameter the same way as other variables do, just use them inside the function. What are you doing with your double `/`?

Comment: I didn't understand what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

Define a distance function between two pixels:

```
def dist(p1, p2):
    return (
        (p1.red - p2.red)**2
        + (p1.green - p2.green)**2
        + (p1.blue - p2.blue)**2
    )**0.5
```

The "best" pixel minimizes the distance to the average pixel:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from statistics import mean

@dataclass
class RgbPixel:
    red: int
    green: int
    blue: int

def best(pixels):
    avg = RgbPixel(
        int(mean(p.red for p in pixels)),
        int(mean(p.green for p in pixels)),
        int(mean(p.blue for p in pixels)),
    )
    return min(pixels, key=lambda p: dist(p, avg))
```

Comment: This is conceptually the better answer, although it ignores the use of `SimpleImage`, which may already have datastructures like the `RgbPixel` defined here, which would then be preferable to use.

Comment: @Grimar I took a quick look at the source for that library and it seemed like the `Pixel` class required an underlying image reference. https://github.com/adilu/simpleimage/blob/master/simpleimage/Pixel.py In short, the library author should probably refactor a bit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `statictics.mean` from all the `red` values, do the same for `green` and `blue`

```
from statistics import mean

def get_best_pixel_list(pixel_list):
    red_average = mean([p.red for p in pixel_list])
    green_average = mean([p.green for p in pixel_list])
    blue_average = mean([p.blue for p in pixel_list])
```

Manually

```
red_average = sum((p.red for p in pixel_list)) / len(pixel_list)
```

Comment: Huh looks like that module was released into the Python standard library in 3.4

Comment: @MateenUlhaq i’ve added

Answer (score 0):

your pixel list should look something like this.
[[pixel1.red, pixel1.green, pixel1.blue],[pixel2.red, pixel2.green, pixel2.blue],[pixel3.red, pixel3.green, pixel3.blue]]

so if you pass the values to the function in this format, you can retrieve it using
pixel_list[1][0] and so on..

Answer (score 0):

- If you could pass list when call function, then do next:

  ```
    class Pixel:
        pass

    def fun(a):
        print(a)
        print(type(a))

    fun([Pixel(), Pixel(), Pixel()])
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [<__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e5f0>, <__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e680>, <__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e6c8>]
  <type 'list'>
  ```
- If you still want to call function with single parameter one by one, then:

  ```
    def fun2(*b):
        bb = list(b)
        print(bb)
        print(type(bb))

    fun2(Pixel(), Pixel(), Pixel())
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [<__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e5f0>, <__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e680>, <__main__.Pixel instance at 0x7f1688e4e6c8>]
  <type 'list'>
  ```